# angular 4: multiple values for option tag

Tags: angular

is there a way of passing multiple variables in the "value" field of my html? I would need (for instance)

```
value = {{option.formula and option.option}}. //whatever syntax that would be if even possible
```

This is what I have so far

```
<select class="form-control" required formControlName="high_availability">
    <option *ngFor="let option of arr" value={{option.formula}} [disabled]="option.disabled"> {{option.option}} </option>
</select>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure if this would work but what if you made value={{[option.formula, option.option]}}

Comment: Do you want to concatenate them in value field?

Comment: @Farasi78 yeah, that what the first thing I tried.

Comment: @Mausam yeah, I don't care they way they are sent to the logic behind, as long as I have both values I can work on.

Comment: Seems to work - check this out: https://angular-2ryxbs.stackblitz.io (alert is the value)...here is the code so you can see. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ryxbs

Comment: @Sivvio ok for that, all you need to do is use brackets for value `<option *ngFor="let option of arr" [value]="option" [disabled]="option.disabled"> {{option.option}} </option>`. The difference now is that you have whole object instead of just one property. Then you can just select the ones you want in your component.

Comment: mmm I tried it and it won't work. I'm assuming that since is an object will not get the value inside? Can you put down the precise syntax you used, just in case I'm missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it should work if your intended output is `value = {{option.formula and option.option}}`

```
<select class="form-control" required formControlName="high_availability">
    <option *ngFor="let option of arr" 
            value="{{option.formula}} and {{option.option}}"
           [disabled]="option.disabled"> {{option.option}} </option>
</select>
```

Comment: this is the correct answer. Although the and is not needed. Cheers pal

Comment: One question. Here I am displaying both formula and option in the drop down and given [value]="option.formula", on select one option what will be displayed on the select?

Answer (score 0):

Put the loop outside of your option definition.

```
<select class="form-control" required formControlName="high_availability">
    <ng-contianer *ngFor="let option of arr">
        <option value={{option.formula}} [disabled]="option.disabled"> {{option.option}} </option>
    </ng-container>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps with my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this as I thought the code would be visible better here then comment above. I am using Angular Material but the logic is same.

View

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)"> 
  <mat-option *ngFor="option of arr" [value]="option">
   {{ option.option }}
  </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Component

```
doSomething(event) {
  let mySelectedOption: any = event.source.value
  console.log(mySelectedOption)
}
```